# Why I can't flip the check property using prop() with a multiple selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector

I know usually when multiple classes are needed to select different classes we use `,` and I searched around too to make sure I didn't remember wrong but somehow if I use `,` there's no error but it wouldn't detect the second select only detect the first.  If I call the classes separately then the code would work though.  Can someone let me know what I have done wrong with the jQuery?

this works.

```
if(($('.use-remaining').prop("checked")) || (($('.use-briquettes').prop("checked")))){}
```

but if I do it this way, it wouldn't work

```
if(($('.use-remaining, .use-briquettes').prop("checked"))){}
```

I have three checkbox. Only one can be checked before a form submits. When form submits it'll check which checkbox is checked. If either one of the classes from the above code is checked then the form will check for a certain inputs if the 3rd checkbox is checked then it'll check for a different validation.

Just that since those two check boxes have the same inputs to check I figure why not combine them if possible.

Comment: use double quotes

Comment: @KrisRoofe that doesn't change anything...

Comment: plz post your code here

Comment: From [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) ~ *"Description: Get the value of a property for the **first element** in the set of matched elements."* Ie, out of the set of all `use-remaining` **and** `use-briquettes` classed elements, it is only checking the `checked` property of the first one

Comment: @KrisRoofe the type of quote used makes absolutely no difference

Comment: @Phil ah ok, so it's because of the `prop()` that's why but if I want to shorten that statement is there a way to? or better just to keep it separate

Comment: @WXR you haven't explained what you're trying to determine from those elements and the checked property so I can't answer your question

Comment: @Phil oh oops my bad let me edit my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> **.prop( propertyName )**
>
> Description: Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.

And also:

> The [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set.

With multiple selectors, it only checks the first selected element's property. Consider the following snippet:

```js
$("#test_button").click(function() {
  console.log($("#test, .test_2").prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="test">
<input type="checkbox" class="test_2">
<button id="test_button">
Test
</button>
<br>
Notice that when the first isn't selected but the second is, it still is false!
```

As you can see, it will be true when *the first element* is checked or all are and the other isn't, or when they are all checked, but not when the second is checked, and the first isn't.

Comment: actually wanted to give Phil the check because he actually explain it first in my comments instead of posting the answer. But really thank you for posting a more detailed with example. Really so hard to choose who to give the check to.

Comment: @WXR I say give it to Phil, he provides a great solution indeed, and gave a great explanation in the comments.

Comment: @WXR my comment was a quick one-liner so I'd say Andrew was probably typing out this answer way before I commented :)

Comment: @AndrewL. really sorry not trying to make it seem bad or anything just I am really happy with both of you providing answers and really wanted to give you both the check.  Long ago I used to ask if I can give checks to two people and then I was told to read the paragraphs in stackoverflow for giving checks to others.  Give it to the one that's closest to the question and satisfied.  What Phil provided was my extra question which I am really happy that I learned more today for alternatives but you posted the answer to my question with a beautiful explanation too.

Comment: Really thx. I am more of a person seeing samples instead of just reading :D

Comment: @WXR No problem, I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

Copying in my comment from above...

From [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> **Description**: Get the value of a property for the **first element** in the set of matched elements

Ie, out of the set of all use-remaining and use-briquettes classed elements, it is only checking the checked property of the first one

In order to tell if there are any checked properties from the set of all `use-remaining` and `use-briquettes` classed elements, you can use [`.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
var anyChecked = $('.use-remaining, .use-briquettes').is(function() {
    return this.checked;
});
```

Comment: actually you answered my question first though. still really need to thank you that other than being the first to explain to me (in comments) but also provide me an alternate of why I want to do it like that.

Comment: @WXR you're welcome. Thanks for improving your question too, it really helps expand the knowledge base here

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Answer (score 1):

When using multiple selectors in a jQuery collection and checking a property it will only check the first element.

```js
var test1 = $(".test1").prop("checked")
var test2 = $(".test2").prop("checked")
var test3 = $(".test1, .test2").prop("checked")

$('p').text(test1 + " " + " " + test2 + " " + test3)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test1" type="checkbox" />
<input class="test2" type="checkbox" checked="true" />

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, `.prop` function returns the property value for the first element in the set of matched elements. Here is one way to achieve desired results:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(".use-remaining:checked, .use-briquettes:checked").length) {
    console.log(".use-remaining and/or .use-briquettes are checked");
  } else {
    console.log("both .use-remaining and .use-briquettes are not checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="use-remaining" class="use-remaining">use-remaining<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="use-briquettes" class="use-briquettes">use-briquettes<br>
  <input type="Submit" value="Click to test">
</form>
```

Alternately, you can test this condition:

```
if ($(".use-remaining, .use-briquettes").is(":checked")) {
}
```